# On-premises replacement for Azure Tables?

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-table-storage

Azure Tables is a great no-sql for in-cloud deployments but we also have some deployments that will be off the public internet. What's the "standalone" counterpart to Azure Tables from a programming model/API/performance perspective?

Comment: Did anything change until today?

Answer (score 1):

There is no on-prem offering for Windows Azure Storage today, here are the features with [Windows Azure Pack](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296435.aspx?CR_CC=200142594).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no direct equivalent of Azure Tables for an on-premises environment. Essentially Azure Table Storage is `Key-Value Pair` based noSql store with `Strong Consistency` programming model. You could look into other key value pair based noSql storage alternatives (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key.E2.80.93value_stores) but I guess you would need to abstract out some functionality if you're looking at just one codebase to target both kinds of stores.